# what is the relation and difference between ipython and jupyter console

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

After the ipython notebook project renamed to jupyter, I always think that `ipython notebook` is the same as `jupyter notebook` and `ipython` shell is just an alias of `jupyter console`. Today I realize that `ipython` does not have `connect_info` magic defined and therefore is not able to be connected to from different backends.

I have the following component installed in my conda:

```
ipython                   6.1.0                    py36_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4    defaults
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0    defaults
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36he59e554_1    defaults
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                    py36_1    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.5.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h7c827e3_0    defaults
```

I have the following questions:

1. What is the relation between the `ipython` of this version and `jupyter console` of this version?
2. Does the `ipython notebook` (deprecated as in `ipython 6.1.0`) another share some components with `jupyter` libraries; or `ipython notebook` is still self-contained?
3. Do `ipython` and `jupyter` have any dependencies?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Architecture Guides — Jupyter Documentation](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/architecture/content-architecture.html) has the authoritative info on how IPython and Jupyter are connected and related.

Specifically, as per [Migrating from IPython Notebook — Jupyter Documentation](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/advanced/migrating.html):

> [The Big Split](https://blog.jupyter.org/the-big-split-9d7b88a031a7) moved IPython’s various language-agnostic components under the Jupyter umbrella. Going forward, Jupyter will contain the language-agnostic projects that serve many languages. IPython will continue to focus on Python and its use with Jupyter.

[Jupyter's architecture](https://test-jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/how_jupyter_ipython_work.html) includes frontends (web or console) and backends (kernels for various languages). IPython console is only about Python and terminal. "IPython Notebook", if it's still a thing (it doesn't work out of the box if I `pip install ipython` as of IPython 5.5.0), is probably a rudiment of the moved components for backward compatibility.

IPython is a dependency of Jupyter:

```
> pip show jupyter
<...>
Requires: ipywidgets, qtconsole, nbconvert, notebook, jupyter-console, ipykernel

> pip show ipython
<...>
Required-by: jupyter-console, ipywidgets, ipykernel
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. The [visual overview of projects](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/visual_overview.html) shows the dependency clear. From both the figure and your reply, it says ipykernel depends on ipython; instead of the other way around. This is interesting. I thought that ipython would be a shell communicating with the core -- ipykernel, the same way as jupyter does. But it is not.

Comment: Thanks for putting the text right from the links, those pages are gone now, but your answer still exists :)

Comment: Link seems to be [here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/architecture/content-architecture.html) now.